# xmlparser in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am using an XML parser along with Oracle to get data from database. When I display it in gridview it is only showing last value instead of 3 values. I am using:

```
doc.LoadXml(str);
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select("//new[@*]");
drNewRow = dt.NewRow();

while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    drNewRow = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Columns.Add("service");
    dt.Columns.Add("entity");
    dt.Columns.Add("updated");

    XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
    XPathNavigator nav3 = iterator.Current.Clone();
    nav2.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    nav3.MoveToParent();

    // lt.Items.Add(nav3.Name + "" + nav2.Name + "" + nav2.va);

    drNewRow["service"] = nav3.Name;
    drNewRow["entity"] = nav2.Name;
    drNewRow["updated"] = nav2.Value;

    dt.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
gw.DataSource = dt;
gw.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `dt.NewRow()` for each new row, not just once above the loop.  Otherwise, you just allocate one row, which you then repeatedly change the data in.

EDIT: don't add the columns inside the loop.  That'll reset the DataTable.  Add the columns outside the loop, but add the new rows inside the loop.

Comment: no its not working.i add dt.newrow() just inside the loop. but it is showing only one row. but if i add in listbox, it gives three values.

Comment: @kawade: Can you update your question to show the new code?  You still might be doing it wrong, but I have no way of knowing without seeing the code.

Comment: @kawade: did you change it not to add columns inside the loop?